# Adding custom events to nginx request handler

Tags: nginx

Hi Is there a way to break the nginx module request handler into phases to simulate async behavior for third party library used in custom module? 
Say I have a library that talks to another server and this library internally manages connections and request processing with backend server. nginx wont be able to generate events on the underlying connections. So approach I can think of is, the nginx handler creates a thread to run the blocking operation and at this point I want to return the control to nginx so it can proceed. Now when the library API call returns I want to post an event in nginx event loop so that it can resume the handler and send back the response to client.

I guess this should be possible? Any pointers on how?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Write upstream handler. Communicate with your thread by Unix or TCP socket, use any protocol you want, when response will be ready your handler will be called again. Use https://github.com/danghvu/nginx-1.4.0/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_memcached_module.c as example

Comment: Thanks Alexander! had similar thought but is this preferred methods as we end using like 1 additional socket to thread. Any idea how does openresty handles this, i believe it runs lua scripts in async mode? I am trying to look at code but not yet able to figure out.

Comment: always when you need to communicate by TCP - you need upstream module handler. Don't see how it is different from Redis for example. The only difference - is your thread startup code. If you need more complex workflow like more then one upstream request per incoming request you should use subrequests.

Comment: Getting this question out of the mothballs, but is there a good writeup somewhere on how to write upstream handlers ? I found this: http://www.evanmiller.org/nginx-modules-guide.html#proxying, but it does not explain how the communication between nginx and the upstream is handled, not what triggers the call to the process_header callback. Does nginx create the communication channel somehow ? Does it push the full client request to the upstream ?